# Leaflet: Load geoJSON file and specific PopUp

Tags: javascript, url, popup, leaflet

In the Leaflet Tutorials (http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/) they show how to associate a Marker or a Feature with a pop up - which can contain HTML code.

I would like the user to be able to specify a specific popup to load using a URL. In the Leaflet Tutorial the URL
    http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/example.html
loads a map and Features - but none of the popups appear until the user clicks on a Feature.

Is there a way to associate a URL (say)
    http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/example.html#Coors%40Field
with a specific Feature so that it displays automatically when the user specifies the URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to interpret what you're exactly asking, but it seems to me that you want to open a popup automatically when the [hash portion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash) of the [location of the current document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/location) matches some property of a geographical feature.

So instantiate your layers, then loop through the features of your `GeoJSON` using [`L.GeoJSON.eachLayer()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#layergroup-eachlayer), checking if the name matches the hash:

```
var group = L.geoJSON(geojson, {...}).addTo(map);

group.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    if ('#' + layer.feature.properties.name === document.location.hash) {
        layer.openPopup();
    }
});
```

Several things to keep in mind:

- Store a reference to the instance of `L.GeoJSON` so you can manipulate it (call its `eachLayer()` method).
- When `L.GeoJSON` instantiates a leaflet layer (a `L.Marker`, `L.Polyline` or `L.Polygon`), it will store the GeoJSON feature as a property of the newly created layer, thus `layer.feature`.
- The hash portion of `document.location` is a string that always starts with `#`. You should clean it up beforehand, paying extra attention to [URL encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Comment: @KirbyJames thank you for your feedback to Ivan. Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to **accept** the answer that helped you solve your issue.